# error in hadoop mapreduce program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I am trying to write data from hbase to hdfs and encountered this error in compilation. Is it problem with the reducer code or something else?

HbaseFile.java:36: setReducerClass(java.lang.Class) in org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class)
                job.setReducerClass(CountWordReducer.class);
                   ^
HbaseFile.java:38: setOutputPath(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf,org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) in org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat cannot be applied to (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the packages you are using you are mixing the older and new api.  To fix this problem you will have to pick one and use it consistently.

Notice your Job is the new api `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job`.  But you're trying to use the old api to set the outputpath, I can tell because it takes the old JobConf `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf`.

If you see "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce", and "org.apache.hadoop.mapred" in your code at the same time, you are probably mixing the api's and should change things around to pick just one.